# Cannot retrieve contact's phone numbers

Tags: java, contacts, gdata, phone-number

Even though some contacts have phone numbers, the following Java method cannot retrieve them. The same thing happens with Email addresses.

```
public String displayOne(String contactId) throws IOException, ServiceException {
    String output = "";
    contactId = contactId.replaceAll("base", "full");
    ContactEntry contact = service.getEntry(new URL(contactId),ContactEntry.class);
    Name name = contact.getName();
    FullName fullName = name.getFullName();

    output += "Contact details of <b>"+fullName.getValue()+"</b> <br/>";

    java.util.List<PhoneNumber> phoneNumbers = contact.getPhoneNumbers();
    for (PhoneNumber pn : phoneNumbers) {
        output += pn.getPhoneNumber()+"<br/>";
    }

    output += "<br/><br/>";

    java.util.List<Email> emails = contact.getEmailAddresses();
    for(Email email : emails) {
        output += email.getAddress()+"<br/>";
    }

    return output;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The `phoneNumbers` is not empty and  `pn.getPhoneNumber()` is not null or empty string ? ps please rather use a `SringBuilder` than output +=

Comment: From some contacts it displays phone numbers and from some it doesn't. They all have phone numbers though.

Comment: Are there any items in the lists?  are you using hibernate (lazy loading) ?

Comment: No, the list is empty. emails.isEmpty() returns true.

Comment: What's the URL ? from documentation the url should be something like 'http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?q='

Comment: The contactId already is as you mention. It's actually a URL. I have read that the gdata api is somewhat depreciated. Maybe something has changed in the internals of the system and the gdata API is unreliable anymore.